# Laravel, WAMP, can't access routes on different pc

Tags: php, laravel, apache, http, wamp

i installed wamp on my windows server 2012 and put my laravel project inside it. I configured the wamp server to allow people from my network to connect to the website. I also put a different website project inside wamp, just to see if everything works there.

When i access it from localhost, everything is working correctly. See picture below:

[image]

But as soon as i try to access it from a different pc, all routes stop working. The URL which i use to connect to the website is: "http://10.20.200.51:8080/magnolia-laravel/public/". This site loads correctly, and i can see my home page. screenshot below:

[image]

But as soon as i click a link that changes my url to "../public/task" or "../public/register", i immediately get a "not found" error. See screenshot below:

[image]

Can someone please help me fix that problem?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

EDIT: The other Website is working, because it does not work with routes, but with ".php" Files in the url. So all the pages get loaded correctly, when inputing the url like this: "http://10.20.200.51:8080/magnolia/index.php" or "http://10.20.200.51:8080/magnolia/db.php?type=input"

My web.php file in the routes folder looks like this:[image]

Accessing all those routes from localhost works fine, but when i try to access those routes from a different computer, it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it myself. i configured a dns server and changed the vhost configuration to point to a subdomain of the website, so i can use my routes again. I also changed the .htaccess file, because i had the problem that i could only go to my routes when i wrote ".../index.php/". With this code, i can access all routes without any problem.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```